# Can I create a Flutter App which downloads videos in the Background?

Tags: flutter, project, implementation, state-management

I want to create a Instagram Reels Downloader App using Flutter,
**but the problem arises here ->**

[image: See I want my App to be in this list]

- I want to display MyApp in the share list so that link can be shared directly....

**Question:**
*1. Does this feature only available in Native Android Development?*

Answers from other experienced Flutter developers.